# Using .\ inside tikzpicture causes issues crashes

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I want to produce MATLAB prettified code with MATLAB code highlighted with `tikz` background. The environment itself works. Using `.\` causes error. `alsoletter={.\\}` in `\lstdefinestyle` does not seem to work

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{calc}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{bigstrut}

% Inline MATLAB
% BEGIN_FOLD

\newlength{\widthMinimum}
\newcommand{\matlabline}[1]
{%
    \setlength{\widthMinimum}{\minof{\widthof{#1}}{\linewidth}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        
        \node[text width=\widthMinimum, align=flush left, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt, anchor=base] (basmah) {\bigstrut#1};
        
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            
            \fill[Ivory1, opacity=1] (basmah.south west) rectangle (basmah.north east);
            
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{listings}

% ========== MATLAB codes packages =========
% BEGIN_FOLD

\usepackage[]{matlab-prettifier}
% BEGIN_FOLD

% Inline code
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{matlab-inline}{
    style=Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\color{DodgerBlue3},
    alsoletter={.\\},
    literate=
    *{.\\}{\textcolor{IndianRed1}{.\textbackslash{}}}{1}, % .\
}

\lstset{style=matlab-inline}

% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=frame, allowframebreaks=0.99]
    
%   \matlabline{\lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|.\|}
    
    \lstinline[style=matlab-inline]|.\|
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Passing fragile content like a listing as an argument to another macro is usually not a good idea.

Comment: it has nothing to do with tikz. Already `\newcommand{\matlabline}[1]{#1}` will fail. You can not use verbatim like material as argument. The code then can no longer adapt the catcodes.

Comment: If your goal is to have some coloured background behind your listing, have a look at the `tcblisting` environment from the tcolorbox package.